# Selenium/Webdriver track page movement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application in test that renders a very very large gantt chart. Most elements are not rendered until the scroll event fires and they are needed (using angular and class names etc). I need to be able to move in all directions and make assertions on these elements.

The particular issue is verification of visibility. I have the following:

```
    private Point AssessElementOutOfViewport()
    {
        var workingViewportMovement = new Point();

        // Essentially the top right of our webpage should ALWAYS be 0,0
        var currentViewportWidth = (int) driver.ExecuteJavaScript<long>("return window.innerWidth");
        var currentViewportHeight = (int) driver.ExecuteJavaScript<long>("return window.innerHeight");

        if (element.Location.X > currentViewportWidth | element.Location.X < 0)
        {
            workingViewportMovement.X = element.Location.X - currentViewportWidth;

            if (workingViewportMovement.X < 20 && workingViewportMovement.X > 0)
            {
                workingViewportMovement.X = 20;
            }
        }

        if (element.Location.Y > currentViewportHeight | element.Location.Y < 0)
        {
            workingViewportMovement.Y = element.Location.Y - currentViewportHeight;

            if (workingViewportMovement.Y < 150 && workingViewportMovement.Y > 0)
            {
                workingViewportMovement.Y = 150;
            }
        }

        return workingViewportMovement;
    }
```

This is just not good enough. It only works when the page is in it's default state. Once I have moved the page on the first check, the next element will want to move by an amount that is not viable, and after one whole page, it will move the page a whole page and the element will still not be visible.

I can make do with the above for now, BUT, I am keen to not reinvent the wheel.

This surely MUST already be dealt with?

I have scoured here, the WebDriver/ChromeDriver/Selecnium documentation and found no properties or methods that aid in keeping track of the 'offset' the viewport has been manipulated through over time/since page load.

Any alternative approaches I should consider?

As it stands I'm just going to attach a Point object to my wrapped driver and keep track of it myself....?

Comment: No, there is no Selenium code that does anything like this. I'm confused as to why you are trying to track an element's position with a variable when you can get it's location at will. Why doesn't `AssessElementOutOfViewport` return a bool... `true` if it's in the viewport, `false` if it's not? You are also not considering the width and height of the element. You need to decide if "in the viewport" means the entire element or any part of it and make appropriate changes.

Comment: I am not trying to track the elements position, I ideally wish to track the relative position of the webpage. Consider the following example:
My viewport is like 1920 x 1080. Element 1 is one 'page' down (1080px down). element 2 is 2 'pages' down (2160px).

If on page load I get the current position of element 1 and move the page so it is visible, everything is fine, but the same method would say that element 2 now requires 2 pages worth of scrolling, so it would do that, and then element 2 wouldn't be visible, as it would be 1 page above the viewport?

Comment: Have you tried using the JS method, `scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: I have, unfortunately this is only useful in browsers that have full support of CSS 4. In general it will probably suffice. I think perhaps this will end with a feature request to the Selenium guys as I feel this would be a useful concept to represent in the driver class....

Comment: This method is fully supported in all major browsers, see [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Yea as I say I am using it for a number of instances. My product has a very large graph and it is this I am manipulating. For reasons I cannot explain, I cannot scroll the window or use the 'normal' scroll bars. I have to update the scrollTop and left on a particular element and that will result in my other element coming into view. So in order to be able to do this I will need to keep track of the relative transform the page has gone through. DW - I'll close this issue it's clear there is no buy in to this as a concept.